# USB port recurring power interference

Tags: linux, usb, audio, power

I'm investigating a noise interference (high pitch glitches) that is occuring on my USB powered audio interface (Motu M4) every ~60 seconds (and last around 2 seconds) using a Linux computer (Manjaro, Kernel 5.9.1 RT). Is there, in Linux systems, some kind of recurring change of state in the power delivered to the USB ports ? If yes, can that be (conditionally) disabled safely (and how) ?

I've been having a browse in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/` and `/sys/module/usbcore/drivers` and the [Linux API documentation](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/driver-api/usb/index.html) but without any luck.

**Edit :** (few precisions)

- It works fine on a Windows computer.
- The problem persists when using a USB live AV Linux (on both the same and a different PC).
- Having the PC on *battery mode* or *plugged in* has no impact on the outcome.

Comment: Have you checked external causes, such as a cell phone near a cable or the PC itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was specific to the audio-interface itself (Motu M4). [That comment](https://panther.kapsi.fi/posts/2020-02-02_motu_m4#comment-5372434152) describes both the issue and the fix.

Upgrading Kernel to version >= 5.11 did the trick.